# Serenity v5.0 - Impersonation is not working

Tags: c#, impersonation, asp.net-core-5.0, serenity-platform

based on https://serenity.is/docs/migration/v3-to-v5, Impersonation is not working in Serenity v5.0

```
public class UserAccessor : IUserAccessor, IImpersonator
{
```

Startup.cs:
`services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, UserAccessor>();` getting error

> There is no implicit reference conversion from 'UserAccessor' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService'

Please help.

Comment: In the article,the code is `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, Serenity.Web.HttpContextUserAccessor>();`,it's `HttpContextUserAccessor`,not `UserAccessor`.

Comment: I tried multiple ways, can't make it work
`There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Serenity.Web.HttpContextUserAccessor' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService'.`

Comment: You can share more details about your code.

Comment: {
    private ImpersonatingUserAccessor impersonator;

    public UserAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        impersonator = new ImpersonatingUserAccessor(new HttpContextUserAccessor(httpContextAccessor), 
            new HttpContextItemsAccessor(httpContextAccessor));
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal User => impersonator.User;

    public void Impersonate(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        impersonator.Impersonate(user);
    }

    public void UndoImpersonate()
    {
        impersonator.UndoImpersonate();
    }
}

Comment: `userAccessor.Impersonate(...)`
My own code in between
`userAccessor.UndoImpersonate()`

Comment: add `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, UserAccessor>();` and change `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, AuthorizationService>();` to `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, Serenity.Web.HttpContextUserAccessor>();`

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationService, Serenity.Web.HttpContextUserAccessor>();` error `There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Serenity.Web.HttpContextUserAccessor' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService'.`

Comment: https://github.com/serenity-is/Serene/blob/master/Serene/Serene.Core/Initialization/Startup.cs#L126
https://github.com/serenity-is/Serene/blob/master/Serene/Serene.Core/Modules/Administration/User/Authentication/UserAccessor.cs#L8